# Custom need (manage places showed on a world map) with Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm a new user of Joomla and I'm starting a Joomla project (v3) where I need to display a world map with markers. These markers must be managed by admins through a basic CRUD (name, latitude, longitude). Admins must be able to create, update or delete markers, and these markers must be shown on a Leaflet map. I suppose creating a new plugin is the solution, but I don't know how to start and proceed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: OSModul is a free Joomla extension that displays multiple markers on a Leaflet map which may solve your problem or which may provide example code for you. See https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/osmodul and https://github.com/Schlumpf/osmodul for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll take a look !